# Preferably jQuery / probably PHP: get content of H1 to TITLE for SEO

Tags: php, jquery, seo, title

Is there a way to get the content of a H1 transferred to the TITLE tag and at the same time making it SEO-friendly?

I'm not going into detail why I want this, but I'd rather give you a clear example. I have this:

```
<h1>Site name / Category / Page title</h1>
```

And I want to copy that to the TITLE of that certain page:

```
<title>Site name / Category / Page title</title>
```

The easiest for me would be to do this with jQuery, but I guess that's not going to be safe for search engine robots?

Answer (score 2):

You're right: the robots won't notice, as they only look at the html in your server response. Use PHP instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use PHP. I think the "easiest" way is to use something like this:

```
<?php

$pageTitle = 'Site name / Category / Page title';

?>
...
<title><?php echo $pageTitle ?></title>
...
<h1><?php echo $pageTitle ?></h1>
...
```

You might want to look into a template system.

Answer (score 0):

Try (i assume you have only one h1-tag on that page)

```
$('title:first').html($('h1').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you generate the page on the server side with the title tag being the one you would like? If you set the title using jQuery, robots won't see it as they only look on the pure html.

Answer (score 0):

You could use directly as below

jQuery('html title').html(jQuery('h1').html());

OR

jQuery('html title').html(jQuery('#h1_id').html());

Consider h1_id as id of the  tag